# force:createRecord Not working in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

```
({
    createRecord : function(component) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        console.log(createRecordEvent);
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "contact" 
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div style="width:30%;height:100px;" id="FlipcardContainer" />

    <script>
        function initLookup() 
        {
             $Lightning.use("c:TestInVisualforce", function(){
             $Lightning.createComponent("c:force_createRecord",{},"FlipcardContainer",
                 function(cmp) {
                     console.log('Component created, do something cool here');
                 });

             });
         }
          initLookup();
    </script>
```

Comment: This method is supported in lightning only.

Comment: @Sachin Some events are supported only inside SF1 container

Comment: Sachin, force:xxx events works only in one/one.app container, which implies both sf1 and lightning experience.

Comment: Does anybody know what is the workaround for this , if this needs to be used from visualforce page ?